# App/Service for customizable online reports?

Tags: web-apps, reporting

I'm building a SaaS product for my customers that will need a feature where a variety of data is shown to the user in custom-generated or canned reports...

I'd love to not have to code this functionality myself and pay someone software/service to front-end the data to my users.

Any suggestions for an awesome looking product?

Comment: So, you will host the software, and your users will be able to use it via the web, right? Open Source, free, budget?

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Pentaho](http://community.pentaho.com/) for this and can recommend it.

In Pentaho, there are 2 concepts: Dashboards and Reports.

A **dashboard** can be defined by anyone online, and is immediately visible online. It is interactive:

[image: dashboard]

A **report** (typically a several-pages PDF) is usually defined using a standalone program, and can be generated/downloaded by online visitors. It can also be viewed as HTML, but still will look like it is made for paper:

[image: report]

It is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear that you don't want to program this yourself, but you must at least do the queries and reports, for this purpose, i recommend you to try [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which is easy to use and let you create reports and dashboards (from query to final design) with pure drag and drop, yet if you want to tweak things it pretty easy to do as well.

As this is not SaaS you must host it in your server (it requires a Windows Server) but you can easily integrate it with any technology (even pure HTML sites) using [Web Report Widgets](http://dbxtra.com/documentation/#topic/report-web-service/web-report-widget/web_report_widget.htm).

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist

Comment: Am I understanding it right: are my website visitors who are seeing reports for their particular data points, considered named users and are subject to license fees?

Comment: Every person who see reports will require a named user, if you're worried about the number of users required, there is an unlimited users option.